# Create several multiplication tables instead of one at a time saved to several .txt files

Tags: python

I want to create several multiplication tables by telling this python program how many I want to make. Then, have the program create that number of multiplication tables saved to that same number of created .txt files. I want one table per .txt file. What code do I need to add and how do I do it? Thanks for your time.

This is the program I want to add the functionality to:

```
def tablep():
    n=int(input("Enter a Number:"))
    start=int(input("Enter a start:"))
    end=int(input("Enter an end:"))

    file=open("*table.txt","a")

    if start<end:
        for i in range(start,end+1):
            s = str(n) + "*" + str(i) + "=  " + str(n*i)
            file.write(s)
            file.write("\n")
            print(n,"*",i,"=",n*i)

    elif start>end:
        for i in range(start,end,-1):
            s = str(n) + "*" + str(i) + "=" + str(n * i)
            file.write(s)
            file.write("\n")
            print(n, "*", i, "=", n * i)

    file.close()

w = tablep()
```

Example output I want in each file to have. This is just one of the files containing the multiplication table with 3:

```
3*0=    0
3*1=    3
3*2=    6
3*3=    9
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From my understanding of your question, you want each txt file to be unique based on the start and end inputs, so you need to just loop over *n* times:

```py
def tablep():
    n=int(input("Enter a Number:")) # number of txt files

    for x in range(0, n):
        start=int(input("Enter a start:"))
        end=int(input("Enter an end:"))
        f_path = "table_" + str(x) + ".txt" # this will numerate each table 
        file = open(f_path, 'w+') # 'w+' tag will create a file if it doesn't exist
        if start<end:
            for i in range(start,end+1):
                s = str(n) + "*" + str(i) + "=  " + str(n*i)
                file.write(s)
                file.write("\n")
                print(n,"*",i,"=",n*i)

        elif start>end:
            for i in range(start,end,-1):
                s = str(n) + "*" + str(i) + "=" + str(n * i)
                file.write(s)
                file.write("\n")
                print(n, "*", i, "=", n * i)

        file.close()
```

Comment: Thank you, this helped. Have a nice day.